# Detect presence of a URL in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am analysing a dataset of Tweets for a project and want to create a new feature which gives either a binary value indicating the presence of a URL or a decimal value indicating the number of URLs. I am not very experienced with pandas and up to now I have just been using simple features such as length and containing a few words (see below)

```
df['LEN']=df.TWEET.str.len()
df['HAS_WORD_CHECK_OUT']=df.TWEET.str.contains('check out')
```

Since URLs can be in so many different formats ([www.website.com](http://www.website.com), https://www.website.com, website.com, etc.), I can't find a solution on how to create this feature. If anyone knows a way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

That's the regular expression I used in my project, work also for both of the cases: "www.website.com", "https://www.website.com"

```
def remove_urls_from_string(s):
    return True if re.sub(r'''(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))''', " ", s) != s else False
df['Binary_HAS_WORD_CHECK_OUT'] = df['HAS_WORD_CHECK_OUT'].apply(remove_urls_from_string)
```

Comment: I think this one only works for links with format https://www.website.com(/subdir). I'm trying to make it work for all types of formats

Comment: For which format this doesn't work?

Comment: There are a lot of questions&anwers on this subject, try to find one that fits your case.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use  `requests` to check a valid URL. And online you can find amazing regex people have already made to find URLS! Using those you can both find users and then check them if they're valid!

```py
import re
import requests

tweet = 'everyone, head to my stores at http://www.buystuff.com/shirts and at www.codeman.com'
urls = re.findall(r"\b((?:https?://)?(?:(?:www\.)?(?:[\da-z\.-]+)\.(?:[a-z]{2,6})|(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(?:(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:(?:(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:(?:(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(?::[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(?:ffff(?::0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:(?:(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(?:25[0-5]|(?:2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])))(?::[0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])?(?:/[\w\.-]*)*/?)\b", tweet)

for i in urls:
    if i.startswith('http') != True:
        i = 'https://'+i
    try:
        response = requests.get(i)
        print(f"{i} is valid and exists on the internet")
    except requests.ConnectionError as exception:
        print(f"{i} does not exist on Internet")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions combined with .str.contains to detect patterns in strings as well as specific words.

```
import pandas as pd
example = pd.DataFrame({'TWEET':['hello',
                             'I visited www.google.com', 
                             'goodbye', 
                             'I like https://www.bbc.co.uk', 
                             'I like wwwhales','checkout imdb.edu']})
```

I have taken the url regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url), it works for my test cases above but you might want slightly different classifications, in which case search for something different. You can also test the regexes [here](https://pythex.org/).

```
url_regex = r'[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)'

example.TWEET.str.contains(url_regex,regex=True)
# [False, True, False, True, False, True]
```